# How to input a character using its character code for a custom font

Tags: fonts, symbols, characters, font-encodings

Apologies in advance, I am new to LaTeX. Feel free to point me in the direction of an already answered thread.

I have a custom font that I wish to use in my article for certain mathematical characters not contained within Unicode. I am able to load the .ttf font file, though the character I desire has no keystroke associated with it. In character map, the character code is 0x96, is there a way I can use this to input the character

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Try `\char"96`.